# Representing a Shapefile with OpenLayers3

Tags: shapefile, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to represent a shapefile over an [ICC](http://www.icgc.cat/en/Public-Administration-and-Enterprises/Services/Online-services-Geoservices/WMS-i-WMTS/WMS-of-raster-cartography) raster map using OpenLayers3. I'm quite new to OpenLayers3 and GIS, so I'm still trying to figure out how it works.

So far I've deduced I need to transform my `.shp` file to `GeoJSON` in order to load it as a vector layer in my map. So, using QGIS I've saved my data as a `GeoJSON`. This is what my sample Shapefile looks like in QGIS:

[image: Shapefile in QGIS]

My resulting `GeoJSON` has an array of near 2850 features like this:

```
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "ID_Segment": 50,
        "NACHr10000": 0.723431,
        "NACHr1200": 0.998081,
        "NACHr1600": 0.979102,
        "NACHr2000": 0.961284,
        "NACHr2400": 0.935882,
        "NACHr3000": 0.901504,
        "NACHr400": 1.145995,
        "NACHr5000": 0.821419,
        "NACHr800": 1.012412,
        "NACHrN": 0.64815,
        "Segment_Le": 15.553003
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [431676.733607147063594, 4581831.752044225111604],
            [431692.099358807899989, 4581834.158185890875757]
        ]
    }
},...]
```

I'm loading my map (the map works fine) and my `GeoJSON` this way:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      title: 'Global Imagery',
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://geoserveis.icc.cat/icc_mapesbase/wms/service?',
        params: {LAYERS: 'mtc10m', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
      })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'Sample',
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '/data/layers/sample.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [2.17, 41.2],
    zoom: 8,
    maxResolution: 0.703125
  })
});
```

The fact is I can't see any data over my map but I don't get any error on the console either. So I have two questions:

1. I don't really know which coordinates system is using my shapefile. Does `[431676.733607147063594, 4581831.752044225111604]` makes any sense to my EPSG:4326 View?
2. How could I style those *LineString* features in order to make them really visible on the map (maybe they are there and I just can't see them...)

Comment: The coordinates in your shapefile are not in EPSG:4326, which seems to be the problem. Once you fix that, it should work

Comment: Thank you @DevdattaTengshe! Is there any way to identify in which CRS are my coordinates?

Comment: Look at the .prj file that came along with your shapefile. That file stores the CRS information.

Comment: I'll have to talk to my client because I didn't get any `.prj` file... Thanks for your help @DevdattaTengshe!

Comment: can you tell me the tool that could transform the shpfile to geojson?More thanks.

Comment: @Black_GISer : try https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js